# Recieving back JSON from php POST using jQuery / AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I am trying for the first time to make a POST response in a sample using search suggestions.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    if (searchField.length > 1) {

        $.ajax({
            url : "search_query.php",
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data : {
                query : searchField
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var output = '<div>';
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (val.item.search(searchField) != -1) {
                        output += '<p><a href="#">' + val.item + '</a></p>';
                    };
                });
                $('#search_results').html(output);          
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Can anyone show me how to properly parse a JSON response?

Comment: There is no "in" in this code.  Is there other code that uses "in", or is that in fact the response from the POST?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I had written the wrong error message down.

Comment: OK.  Can you click "edit" and post the correct error messages?

Comment: I deleted it several minutes back.  The error message was `output is not defined` - which was the issue.

Comment: OK. guess you solved it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't defined `output` as a variable, the below should work.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    if (searchField.length > 1) {

        $.ajax({
            url : "search_query.php",
                    dataType : "json",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                query : searchField
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var output = '';
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (val.item.search(searchField) != -1) {
                        output += '<p><a href="#">' + val.item + '</a></p>';
                    };
                });

            }
        })
    };
});
```