# jquery jtable display 2 columns in one column

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud, jquery-jtable

I am writing up a program using jtable from jtable.org and I am trying to display two columns in one column. However, as you can see in the code, it works fine for strivial_name, but for supplier_name_options, it just display the value, not the DisplayText value. I did take a look in JTable API but to no avail. Please help.

Thanks

```
supplier_showname: {
    title: 'Supplier',
    width: '20%',
    create: false,
    edit: false,
    display: function(showname) {
                if(showname.record.supplier_name_options != '000') {
                   return showname.record.supplier_name_options;
                }else {
                   return showname.record.strivial_name;
                }
             }
},                                               
supplier_name_options: {
    title: 'Supplier Name',
    options: 'scripts/orders/showoptions.php',
    list: false
},       

strivial_name: {
    title: 'New Supplier Name (Trivial)',
    list: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new script that returns the option name given the option value and call it via ajax like this example

[AJAX and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912277/recieving-back-json-from-php-post-using-jquery-ajax)

So, Something like this...

```
function optionnamefromid(optionid){
  var output = '';
        $.ajax({
            url : "optionnamefromid.php",
                    dataType : "json",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                query : optionid
            },
            success : function(data) {

                 output = data.optionname
                    };
            });
return output;
}
```

then call that from the custom jTable code

```
 if(showname.record.supplier_name_options != '000') {
               return optionnamefromid(showname.record.supplier_name_options);
            }else {
               return showname.record.strivial_name;
            }
```